# Is there a way to prevent Vscode from switching windows while navigating the code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I use C and typically use two vertical windows.

Is there a way to prevent switching the window while navigating the code?

I often navigate through call graphs by jumping into symbol definitions (F12) and then jump back and forth in the code (ctrl+alt+-/ctrl+shift+-).

What really distracts me is that VSCode decides to open the definition due to some strange logic in a different window, replacing what was selected to be shown there and messing up the context.

For example, jumping to a definition would happen in the same window instead of switching to one of the other windows.

Thanks

Comment: One thing is that VS (I suppose also VS Code) jumps to the tab in which a given file is already open. If you typically switch only between a handful of files, pre-open them all and put the tabs on the editor window of you choice; those tabs should be used when you navigate to places in those files. A simple way to arrive there incrementally is to manually move all tabs you jump to to the editor window of your choice and make them "permanent" (I think the pin symbol). That way you arrive automatically at an open collection of the relevant files on the window of your choice, after a while.

Comment: I've noticed and used the same. It is more convenient when project is smaller rather than big. I've got the pleasure to work in bigger codebase and pre-organizing and -managing tabs starts to feel inconvenient quite soon.
Since this can't be too difficult feature to be implemented, I should probably make a feature request (have to find a way to do that).

Comment: @vraa Just go to the issue tab of the vscode repository on github

Answer (score 0):

Setting workbench.editor.revealIfOpen to false helps.

First problem is with the terms; when I said 'I use two vertical windows' I meant, I had navigated in the menu to View->Editor Layout->Two columns.

So 'vertical windows' is alias for 'two columns', which is actually 'two editor groups'.

Many thanks for https://github.com/IllusionMH for the help.